# Context Variables in WAR file of a Talend job

Tags: sql-server, excel, talend

I have designed a job in talend to copy data from Excel sheet to SQL server tables. In my job I am using context variables for database connection and excel file location.

I am exporting my job as a Web Service (WAR) file. Now if I want to run a job with different database or with different excel file how do I change default values of context variables?

Comment: You don't want to do this. The database and excel files you use in your job would need to be a local resource to your job. So making it a web service would be utterly pointless.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this..you can either do context load from flat file using option of implicit context load from file, database options at job settings (Extra) tab in talend. you also have talend component to load contexts during job execution.

you can also add new context configurations to existing context groups and while export your job you can select one of those context configurations to be used...like create dev, test and prod configuration and while exporting job for test you can use test configure context..

Comment: This answer talks about how to set/change context variables in a normal job rather than specifically when the job is deployed and ran as a web service. There are a lot more complications here, especially with how you pass data to the web service.